# How do I save the values that I applied the filter to a new index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How do I save the values that I applied the filter to a new index?

[image: preview]

The picture is extracted only the values I want through the filter function.
I'd like to save this extracted value to a new index.

Thank you very much for letting me know.

```
GET 0503instgram_csv/_search?_source=message&filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Reindex](http://POST%20_reindex%20%7B%20%20%20%22source%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22index%22:%20%22my-index-000001%22%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22dest%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22index%22:%20%22my-new-index-000001%22%20%20%20%7D%20%7D) Api, Yuo can create new index with desired mapping and settings then project your old index with ingested data into the new one just you created. The source and destination can be any pre-existing index, index alias, or new index. However, the source and destination must be different. Consider below example, Where we created new index with the name "new_index" with some basic mappings inside PUT properties Api.

```html
PUT /new_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  “mappings”: {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "id":{
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "paid": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
```

Finally your Reindex Api may look like as below.

```html
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

Comment: The values I extracted will not be stored in the new index.